# Check if selected dropdown value is empty using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the dropdown in question:

```
<select name="data" class="autotime" id="EventStartTimeMin">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is check if the current value is empty:

```
if ($("EventStartTimeMin").val() === "") {
   // ...
}
```

But it does not work, even though the value is empty. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You forgot the `#` on the id selector:

```
if ($("#EventStartTimeMin").val() === "") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for .net if _EventStartTimeMin_ where an asp.net control the code would be:     `if ($("#<%= EventStartTimeMin.ClientID %>").val() === "") {
    // ...
}`

Comment: @Juanito I know, but how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: For the negation of the expression, just use `!==`, of course.

Comment: Also note that if the default selected option is `disabled`, the value of the `select` element will be `null` instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this also-

```
if( !$('#EventStartTimeMin').val() ) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: This might not be desired, e.g. in case when 0 is a valid option value.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `.change()` event as well as using `#` to target element by `id`:

```
$('#EventStartTimeMin').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()===""){ 
        console.log('empty');    
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68G9t/)**

Comment: The problem with just using change is that if the last field requires keyboard input, there is no change until the viewer clicks on something, leaving them befuddled. Use .on('change, keyup',function(){ }) instead.

Comment: Yeah i noticed you have to put it inside a change. But why doesn't it work without a change? Nice answer btw!